# Magento 2 : Getting Internal Server Error While Deleting Multiple Users

Tags: magento2, admin, customer

I am using Magento 2.1.7. From admin panel, getting an internal server error on deleting the more than 50 customer from mass action.

Comment: try to increase your memory limit.

Comment: You should check your PHP error log and see what is causing the 500 error.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I tried already but still faced this issue.

Comment: Its configuration errors in the virtual host file.